# Genson Polymorphic / Generic Serialization

Tags: java, json, serialization, json-deserialization, genson

I am trying to implement a JSON serialization in Java with [Genson](http://owlike.github.io/genson/) 1.3 for polymorphic types, including:

- `Number`s
- Arrays
- `Enum` classes

The SSCCE below demonstrates roughly what I am trying to achieve:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.owlike.genson.Genson;
import com.owlike.genson.GensonBuilder;

/**
 * A Short, Self Contained, Compilable, Example for polymorphic serialization
 * and deserialization.
 */
public class GensonPolymoprhicRoundTrip {

    // our example enum
    public static enum RainState {
        NO_RAIN,
        LIGHT_RAIN,
        MODERATE_RAIN,
        HEAVY_RAIN,
        LIGHT_SNOW,
        MODERATE_SNOW,
        HEAVY_SNOW;
    }

    public static class Measurement<T> {
        public T value;
        public int qualityValue;
        public String source;

        public Measurement() {
        }
        public Measurement(T value, int qualityValue, String source) {
            this.value = value;
            this.qualityValue = qualityValue;
            this.source = source;
        }
    }

    public static class DTO {
        public List<Measurement<?>> measurements;

        public DTO(List<Measurement<?>> measurements) {
            this.measurements = measurements;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Genson genson = new GensonBuilder()
        .useIndentation(true)
        .useRuntimeType(true)
        .useClassMetadataWithStaticType(false)
        .addAlias("RainState", RainState.class)
        .useClassMetadata(true)
        .create();

        DTO dto = new DTO(
                new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(
                        new Measurement<Double>(15.5, 8500, "TEMP_SENSOR"),
                        new Measurement<double[]>(new double[] {
                                2.5,
                                1.5,
                                2.0
                        }, 8500, "WIND_SPEED"),
                        new Measurement<RainState>(RainState.LIGHT_RAIN, 8500, "RAIN_SENSOR")
                        )));
        String json = genson.serialize(dto);
        System.out.println(json);
        DTO deserialized = genson.deserialize(json, DTO.class);
    }
}
```

Numbers and Arrays worked well out-of-the-box, but the enum class is providing a bit of a challenge. In this case the serialized JSON form would have to be IMO a JSON object including a:

- type member
- value member

Looking at the `EnumConverter` class I see that I would need to provide a custom `Converter`. However I can't quite grasp how to properly register the `Converter` so that it would be called during **deserialization**. How should this serialization be solved using Genson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great for providing a complete example!

First problem is that DTO doesn't have a no arg constructor, but Genson supports classes even with constructors that have arguments. You just have to enable it via the builder with 'useConstructorWithArguments(true)'.

However this will not solve the complete problem. For the moment Genson has full polymorphic support only for types that are serialized as a json object. Because Genson will add a property called '@class' to it. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/owlike/genson/issues/64) for that.

Probably the best solution that should work with most situations would be to define a converter that automatically wraps all the values in json objects, so the converter that handles class metadata will be able to generate it. This can be a "good enough" solution while waiting for it to be officially supported by Genson.

So first define the wrapping converter

```
public static class LiteralAsObjectConverter<T> implements Converter<T> {
    private final Converter<T> concreteConverter;

    public LiteralAsObjectConverter(Converter<T> concreteConverter) {
        this.concreteConverter = concreteConverter;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(T object, ObjectWriter writer, Context ctx) throws Exception {
        writer.beginObject().writeName("value");
        concreteConverter.serialize(object, writer, ctx);
        writer.endObject();
    }

    @Override
    public T deserialize(ObjectReader reader, Context ctx) throws Exception {
        reader.beginObject();
        T instance = null;
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            reader.next();
            if (reader.name().equals("value")) instance = concreteConverter.deserialize(reader, ctx);
            else throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Encountered unexpected property named '%s'", reader.name()));
        }
        reader.endObject();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Then you need to register it with a ChainedFactory which would allow you to delegate to the default converter (this way it works automatically with any other type).

```
Genson genson = new GensonBuilder()
            .useIndentation(true)
            .useConstructorWithArguments(true)
            .useRuntimeType(true)
            .addAlias("RainState", RainState.class)
            .useClassMetadata(true)
            .withConverterFactory(new ChainedFactory() {
                @Override
                protected Converter<?> create(Type type, Genson genson, Converter<?> nextConverter) {
                    if (Wrapper.toAnnotatedElement(nextConverter).isAnnotationPresent(HandleClassMetadata.class)) {
                      return new LiteralAsObjectConverter(nextConverter);
                    } else {
                      return nextConverter;
                    }
                }
            }).create();
```

The downside with this solution is that **useClassMetadataWithStaticType needs to be set to true**...but well I guess it is acceptable as it's an optim and can be fixed but would imply some changes in Gensons code, the rest still works.

If you are feeling interested by this problem it would be great you attempted to give a shot to that issue and open a PR to provide this feature as part of Genson.

Comment: I implemented a solution based on this and the javadocs for [Factory](http://owlike.github.io/genson/Documentation/Javadoc/com/owlike/genson/Factory.html) and [ChainedFactory](http://owlike.github.io/genson/Documentation/Javadoc/com/owlike/genson/convert/ChainedFactory.html), which also provided relevant code examples.